# Distributing lines of commands using bash script

Tags: bash, process, parallel-processing

I'm trying to implement trivial parallelization where lines of commands are distributed among separate processes. For that purpose I wrote this script that I named `jobsel`:

```
(only "#! /bin/bash" and help message is omitted)

slots=$1
sel=$2

[[ $slots -gt 0 ]] || die_usage
[[ $sel -lt $slots ]] || die_usage

i=0
while read line
do
        (( i % slots == sel )) && eval $line
        i=$(( i + 1 ))
done

# in case the last line does not end with EOL
if [[ $line != "" ]]; then
        (( i % slots == sel )) && eval $line
        i=$(( i + 1 ))
fi
```

I put `eval` because I couldn't use redirection or pipe in the commands without it.

When I run this like `$HOME/util/jobsel 22 0 < cmds` on a console emulator when `cmds` is a file that contains lines like `echo 0 >> out` with increasing numbers, it outputs, as expected, `0, 22, 44...` in separate lines. Good so far.

So I put this to work. But when I ran this through secure shell, I ran it through `at` with backgrounding (ending each line with `&`). Then there is a problem. When I entered 8 lines, 21 processes started! `ps -AFH` printed processes with identical command and different pIDs. All work processes were at the same level, directly under init. My program does not create child processes anyway.

Puzzled, I tried the `echo 0 >> out` script through `at` then the output contained duplicate lines. Still finding it hard to believe, and thinking simultaneous appending might have caused the anomaly, I used other methods to confirm that some lines were run multiple times.

Moreover, there was no such anomaly when everything was run in terminal or when I created separate `at` job for each worker process.

But how can this happen? Is something wrong with my script? Does `at/atd` have some bug?

Comment: Instead of `[[ $(( i % slots )) -eq $sel ]]` do `(( i % slots == sel ))`. Please see [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement) and [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: Have you considered using [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Thank you. I'm applying edit.

Comment: ``at`` seemed to do fine when final ``&`` was omitted. But that is not always the case. So I turned to ``nohups``.

Comment: Also, `((slots > 0 ))` and `((sel < slots ))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU [parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) is what you are trying to implement.

Hint : it works great combined to xargs